# Trying to make the QR code automatic by using random value generated by a function from php

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hi this is my code working fine when you type the text it gets converted into an qr code but i want to make it automatic. I have a php function which generates random number, so instead of typing the text, the qrcode should be generated by the value of that function.

[image]

This is my html page code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
  <input id="text" type="text" value="http" style="width:80%" /><br />
<div id="qrcode"></div>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://davidshimjs.github.com/qrcodejs/qrcode.min.js'></script>

    <script src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my javascript function :

```
var qrcode = new QRCode("qrcode");

function makeCode () {      
    var elText = <?php echo random_str(6); ?> ;

    if (!elText.value) {
        alert("Input a text");
        elText.focus();
        return;
    }

    qrcode.makeCode(elText.value);

}

makeCode();

$("#text").
    on("blur", function () {
        makeCode();
    }).
    on("keydown", function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            makeCode();
        }
    });
```

and this is the php function that i want to implement so that an random number will generate and qrcode will be formed on that basis

```
<?php

function random_str($length, $keyspace = '0123456789')
{
    $str = '';
    $max = mb_strlen($keyspace, '8bit') - 1;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; ++$i) {
        $str .= $keyspace[random_int(0, $max)];
    }
  return $str;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you were using the input-based version you coded the makeCode() function to pull the value for the QRCode from the input box. Now that you are using a literal value you need to modify the makeCode() in respect of how it works with the source number - now a javascript literal value and not a control.

```
function makeCode () {      
    var elText = "<?php echo random_str(6); ?>" ; // note quotes around random no.

    if (elText.length === 0) { // is the random string zero length 
        alert("Random number is blank - weird !");
        return;
    }

    qrcode.makeCode(elText);

}
```

The quotes around the random number from php will protect you from the risk of it returning a blank. I don't know how likely that is but if it did happen then the JS would fail. And since there are no numeric operations on it we can just treat it as a string. In that case we can test it's length and decide from there is we need to make the QRCode.

Comment: now my qr code is generated but of text <?php echo random_str(6); ?>

Comment: Lol - well thats progress ! I'm no php expert It would seem that php did not get the point that it was meant to spit out a number.  Can you compare it to other of your php outputs?

Comment: the random function which i've made is working fine and generating numbers but i didn't know why i'm not able to get a number from that function , i think the calling of php function from javascript is not correct .

Comment: I had assumed you generate your html and JS from php so that php will see the random function directive. How do you generate the output ?

Comment: No actually at first i made the qrcode genrator in html and generating a qrcode by using input but then i need to do it by using the random function in php , so i just need to get a number from the php function and need to use it to generate the qrcode.

Comment: Look at Sofiane's solution.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how your html is rendered

1- if it's from php and you this function is in same file or can be called from this php file, you can do that:

```
<script>
var qrcode = new QRCode("qrcode");
qrcode.makeCode('<?php echo random_str(3); ?>');
</script>
```

2- if it's an html file you can not call the function, you can use ajax to call a php file which give you the value of random and use it

Comment: my php code is in my html file but new QRcode is not working.

Comment: sorry I updated it, you put ths javascript code into the html file, you can replace index.js file

Comment: now a code is being generated but of value equals to <?php echo random_str(3); ?>

Comment: so you are not using php file !! is your file extension  '.php'?

Comment: I mean the file where the qrcode is displayed, is it php file?